# Which is the best way to fix and preserve comet assay slides before staining with Ethidium Bromide?

Tags: lab-techniques, dna-damage

I want to use the method of Single Cell Gel Electrophoresis (comet assay). I have many samples, but I don't have the appropriate microscope. So I have to preserve my slides until the time comes for staining and microscopic analysis. I've read many different protocols, and I can't decide which is the best. Also, after the staining and the analysis, I might need to reuse the same slide. Is that possible? and if yes, what should I do?

Comment: Can you give more information about what protocols you have looked into?

Comment: Most of them use either 100% or gradually increasing percentage of ethanol or methanol. Some suggest to hydrate before the staining and some of them don't. Also some use mounting media at the end and others just a coverslip. I suppose that most of these work but it would be very helpful if I had a specific protocol that I know that will work.

Comment: This could be of use: http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/cyto.a.20071/full